# How to pass values to selected combobox in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

At this moment i am able to display the names of the person in selected combobox, but i want to store the person_id in database instead of person's name . How can i achieve this.

Controller

public function index()
{

```
  $this->Relation->save($this->request->data);
  $this->loadModel('Profile');
  $person= $this->Profile->find('all');
    if($this->request->is('post')){
    }
    $temp = array();
$temp1 = array();

    foreach($person as $person_name)
    {
      $temp[ $person_name['Profile']['id']] =  $person_name['Profile']['id'];
      $temp1[ $person_name['Profile']['first_name']] = $person_name['Profile']['first_name'];

    }
    $this->set('person_name', $temp);
    $this->set('person_id', $temp1);
}
```

View  index.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('person_id',array('multiple'=>true,'label'=>false,'type'=>'select','options'=>$person_name,'selected'=>$person_id)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view index.ctp

```
$data = array_combine($person_id,$person_name);
```

if you print that $data as pr($data);

```
Array
(
[54af7764-dcf8-4355-bcc7-3980c2f436a7] => sandeep
[54af77bb-fe28-4634-a3f9-3980c2f436a7] => prakash

)
```

so your selected combo box will be

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('person_id',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'select','options'=>$data)); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much prakash, this worked like charm. i was banging my head for this from last one day, you solved it within a minute, i totally appreciate your work. once again thank you very much.